# Prevent domain GPO member computer from automatically sleeping or hibernating

Tags: c#

How is doing everybody? I have a problem with my application created in C#. My computer at my job is running Windows 7. My computer is in domain and member of Group Policy in Active Directory.

This group policy is activating to sleep or turning off the display while the application is running.

I created application in C# and want to run this application without turning off the display. What kind of code in C#  can I use to cheat  my computer to think that I’am working with my computer like moving mouse application for not going in sleep mode?

I have read about `SetThreadExecutionState` and:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern uint SetThreadExecutionState(uint esFlags);
public const uint ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000;
public const uint ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x00000001;
public const uint ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = 0x00000002;
```

[in this link](http://www.thewebflash.com/2015/03/prevent-computer-from-automatically.html).

but I don’t know how to use it. Can you guys give some hint? How can I prevent the system or GPO from entering sleep or turning off the display while the application is running.

I appreciate deep for all help!

Comment: Have you tried just calling that function, and then leaving the application open?

Comment: There are some sample C# methods in the article that you link to.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart Thank you for your response. Shall I use it as part of my application I mean those code will be inside my app , or shall I save it as application and run both my app and SetThreadExecutionState  app. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @RenniePet Thank you, but can you send me the link then? I didn't see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an answer, it's just that it's impossible to format code in a comment ...

In your question you post this link: http://www.thewebflash.com/2015/03/prevent-computer-from-automatically.html

It includes several sample C# methods showing how to use the code that you post yourself in your question. For example:

```
// Prevent the system from entering sleep and turning off monitor
private void PreventSleepAndMonitorOff()
{
    NativeMethods.SetThreadExecutionState(NativeMethods.ES_CONTINUOUS | NativeMethods.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | NativeMethods.ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED);
}
```

That's what I tried to point out in my comment.

Edit:

And to answer the question you pose to @Jonathon Reinhart, you should just include this code in your existing application.

Comment: Thank you RenniePet. I missunderstod totaly how to use it but now it's working well. Thank you guys...